# How do you create a graph for $y=-\frac32x$ but $x$ has to be an integer?

Tags: graphing-functions

How do you create a graph for $y=-\frac32x$ but $x$ has to be an integer? I'm not sure how to show the graph is infinite because it is a linear equation, you could put arrows at the end of the line but since $x$ is an integer, it has to be individual points.

Comment: Since you say it is linear do you mean $y= -\frac32x$?

Comment: And are you just looking for a good way to depict this on a hand-drawn graph?

Comment: Yeah, sorry first time using this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try to use MathJax (like TeX) to write your math more clearly.  You can find help on it. I’m editing your original question so you can see an example of the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are looking for but if it’s a good way to graph by hand I think just the discrete points and arrows in some way at the tails is fine.